# Rank, nullity and the number of rows of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, transpose

I have this question here:

> Let $A$ be a matrix with $10$ columns, $dim$ $Null(A)=5$ and $dim$ $Null(A^T)=3$. How many rows does $A$ have?
>
> $a)$ $8$
>
> $b)$ $3$
>
> $c)$ $5$
>
> $d)$ $10$
>
> $e)$ This cannot be determined from the information given

I tried doing it. I know that:

$rank(A)+Nullity(A)=10$

So that means that

$rank(A)+5=10$

$rank(A)=5$

However, I am not really sure how that helps me find the number of rows. I know that  $dim$ $Null(A^T)=3$ but how do I incorporate that into this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Note:}$ $\text{Rank($A$) = dim(rowsp($A$)) = dim(colsp($A$))}$

$\text{Nullity($A^T$) + dim(rowsp($A$)) = Number of rows of $A$}$

$\text{Nullity($A$) + dim(colsp($A$)) = Number of  columns of $A$}$

Comment: Yup I see how that works. I know that the 2nd equation is true but why is $\text{Nullity($A^T$) + dim(rowsp($A$)) = Number of rows of $A$}$ true? How do you obtain that?

Comment: $\text{Nullity($A^T$)}$ is the number of zero rows in RREF of $A^T$ and $\text{dim(rowsp($A$))}$ is the number of pivot rows.

Comment: In other words consider the third equation for $A^T$ then rows become columns and columns become rows. Then we have $\text{Nullity($A^T$) + dim(colsp($A^T$)) = Number of  columns of $A^T$=Number of rows of $A$}$

Comment: I get it now! Thanks so much!